# Unexpected end of JSON input in my Deno HTTP server code

Tags: deno

I'm actually dealing with some issues.

In fact I'm coding an HTTP server with Deno and I have the same problem that I did with Node.js.

I use Postman to simulate POST request to my server.

When I do a Request with the URL of my localhost the server is working:

***The deno server code :***

```js
const listener = Deno.listen({ port: 8000 });
console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:8000`);

for await (const conn of listener) {
  handleNewConnection(conn);
}

async function handleNewConnection(conn: Deno.Conn) {
  for await (const req of Deno.serveHttp(conn)) {
    await handleRequest(req.request, req.respondWith);
  }
}

async function handleRequest(req: Request, resp: any) {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    let body = await req.json();
    console.log(body);
    resp(new Response(null));
  } else {
      console.log(req.method)
    resp(new Response(null));
  }
}
```

***The request that I'm sending in localhost:8000:***

[image: POST request on port 8000]

***What I receive in console.log :***

```json
{
  name: "Molecule Man",
  age: 29,
  secretIdentity: "Dan Jukes",
  powers: [ "Radiation resistance", "Turning tiny", "Radiation blast" ]
}
```

Then I'm gonna show you when I use a Cloudflare tunnel.
This Cloudflare tunnel is directly sending the requests to my server on port 8000.

***The POST request that I'm sending :***

[image: POST request at the URL poc-pdu.44.io]

***What I receive with the console.log() :***

```js
error: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    let body = await req.json();
               ^
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at packageData (deno:ext/fetch/22_body.js:328:16)
    at Request.json (deno:ext/fetch/22_body.js:267:18)
    at async handleRequest (file:///C:/Users/Utilisateur/Projets/poc-pdu/HTTP-serv-deno/http-serv-deno.ts:17:16)
    at async handleNewConnection (file:///C:/Users/Utilisateur/Projets/poc-pdu/HTTP-serv-deno/http-serv-deno.ts:10:5)
```

That's the error, in my opinion, this is due to the time it takes for the request to arrive at it's destination.
I thank all the people who will take the time to respond to this post.

Bye!

Comment: I see the request you are sending is RAW. Are you sending the Content Type headers for JSON as well?

Comment: if you put `let body = await req.json()` in a try/catch block, and print the raw string body in the catch, what do you see?

Comment: Yes the content-type headers is for JSON as well for the request and if i put `let body = await req.json()` in a try and catch block the code goes in the catch and the body is undefined.